# Windows XP equivalent of "tail -f"?

Tags: windows-xp, tail

Is there way have windows XP show me updates to a log file as they happen?  I'm thinking of something similar to `tail -f <file path>` in the linux realm.

Comment: Thanks everyone for those awesome suggestions! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using Windows [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx), you can use [Get-Content](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/get-content.mspx)  < filename > -wait

There's also a [discussion](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0001.html) of a [Windows Server 2003 tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb405955.aspx) package that has a tail program which supports `-f`

Answer (score 7):

I have had good luck with http://sourceforge.net/projects/tailforwin32/.   It has some nice options for fonts, colors and keyword highlighting.  Feels lightweight and fast to me.

Comment: Tail for win32 is a nice GUI application. Highlighting keywords can give you find -f file.txt | grep 'stuff' like functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `tail` program from the [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) project. this is "just" a ported UN*X `tail` command.

Answer (score 3):

We currently use this 
http://www.baremetalsoft.com/wintail/

Answer (score 2):

I use [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which are native win32 ports of common gnu utilities. Then I don't have to bother with cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/) an other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/logexpert/)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout in'side log.

A Java tool I created, able to read local and distant log files using SSH. It is fairly simple to use.

Some more explanations: https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/wiki

Just download the version corresponding to your operating system, or the native jar release executable within your Java Runtime (requires java 8_40 or higher):

https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/releases

You can find a complete documentation (embedded with and in Github's page as well)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a version of `git` installed that comes with `bash` (for instance the one from https://git-scm.com), you can use the `tail` included with that.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround in case of cmd.exe:

1. `find /c /v "" your_file.txt` - will count the number of lines in the file
2. `more +123456 your_file.txt` - will display lines starting from the specified line number

Calculate point 1 result minus tail you need and put it into point 2, and here it is