# How can I see the last lines of a large file in Windows?

Tags: windows

My servers hung, and after a restart it showed me that my hard drive was full (Windows Server 2008). I looked into the problem and it was a  189 GB Tomcat log file!

To find out the cause for the crash, seeing the last 100 lines of the file would be enough.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Do the solution suggested in [Windows XP equivalent of “tail -f”?](http://superuser.com/q/68703) help?

Comment: if it is that big I imagine it is being written to quite frequently. Just delete it then read what it writes new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) is a GUI tool that can be used to monitor changes to a log file in real time.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can also get a command line version of tail here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the log to rotate.  As of right now, your log is just constantly appending to the end, which is causing it to grow constantly.  There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079915/how-to-rotate-tomcat-logs-in-windows-what-is-the-best-method) on the Stack Overflow website which you might want to try.

Comment: I do have log file rotation per day, but for somehow, only that day the file goes huge (usually 300k)

Comment: did you examine the log file to see what was causing it to fill up?

Comment: that's what I want to do :)